# What animal is ערוד (Arod)?

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara

I'm a visual learner. Now, I've been learning Daf 33a in Meseches Brachos and I came across the word **ערוד**, which Rashi explains as a hybrid of a Snake and a Toad. I was wondering if anyone ever saw a picture like that online. Or if there's any more info on that. Or perhaps it means a Lizard?

Comment: Lizards don’t live in burrows, nor are they venomous. Sefaria isn’t much help; they just translate it as “arvad.” If not for the fact that this creature comes up in halachic contexts (BK 37a, Chullin 59a), I’d say that the creature doesn’t actually exist and the whole story is metaphorical.

Comment: I'm sure R' Slifkin says something about it.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Rabbeinu_Bahya%2C_Vayikra.11.2.1?lang=bi -- see Rabbbeinu Bahya here, it is related to the salamander

Comment: I don't really know where you see that at all. However it did make me think more towards a massive venomous dragon @Menachem

Comment: @Moshe  הצב שני מינים האחד שמו ערוד והשני שמו סלמנדר"א it's about halfway through

Comment: Thanks @Menachem

Comment: @Moshe Based simply on description, it sounds like something similar to a Gila Monster, which is a venomous lizard. They do live in holes. Since the Shas is likely not talking about the Americas (not impossible, but not likely) it’s probably talking about a similar creature in Asia or India. Here’s a link with a photo.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gila_monster

Comment: That's exactly what I thought. The Gila monster @YaacovDeane

Comment: @Moshe Another possibility is the Asian Water Monitor, which fits Rashi’s description of being similar to a snake in that it’s tongue is forked like a snake tongue & it lives in India. Here’s a link:   https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asian_water_monitor

Comment: Makes a little more sense. Since the story took place around Asia. Rather then the Gila Monster which is American @YaacovDeane

Comment: I feel as though Steinzaltz provides something at some point in Shas, dont know.

Comment: see https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/ערוד_(חז%22ל)